Add author note in YAML header with link in pandoc
I have a markdown file with a line in the header
---
author: Author\thanks{Institute. Email [test](mailto:test@test.org).}
---

My problem is: the link is not correctly interpreted by pandoc, even though other links are correctly interpreted in the markdown file.
Please let me know if I should provide a MWE. I guess the problem might be easy and I just do not see it.

I assume I'm a bit too late, but in any case:
Pandoc doesn't support Markdown syntax nested in LaTeX syntax. The solution is either to use Markdown syntax for footnotes
---
author: "Author^[Institute. Email [test](mailto:test@test.org).]"
---

or to use LaTeX syntax for the link
---
author: 'Author\thanks{Institute. Email \href{mailto:test@test.org}{test}.}'
---

Note the quoted values, as colons in the value of a YAML string can lead to parsing issues.

If you're writing an academic article, then you might also be interested in this StackOverflow Q&A and in Quarto.
